# How to find out the ID of the item in the other variation in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, splistitem, variations

In SP2013, I am using target variations having `en` as source and `fr` as another variation. In lists I can push to the `fr` side, which means for items if they get approved they appear in the french side with the same ID. However if someone accidentally manually creates items in the french side and deletes it, then when the item gets created from the english item being approved, the ID will be 1 higher in the french side and won't match.

Is there some code that can tell me the item ID?

Note: This is not for pages, this is for a custom list.

Thanks

Comment: I’m not quite sure which item ID you are suggesting, but there is a ObjectID field in the Relationships List that used to store the variation configuration settings, which might do some help. See the article here: https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2011/11/21/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-6-configuration-internals/

Comment: Basically, for each item in the English list, the goal is to find the associated item in the French list, which may have a different id.